# Node JS not displaying my data to the template

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I am querying some data from the Yelp API. Console.log of the business works fine in the terminal, yet when I call that same variable to render in the template, nothing displays.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/*GET Hello World page. */
router.get('/helloworld', function(req, res){
    var first;
    yelp.search({location: "tempe", term: "sandwiches", category_filter: "food"}, function(error, data) {
        var test = JSON.stringify(data); //Changes yelps response to JSON Objects with double quotes
        test = JSON.parse(test); //JSON.parse can now parse correctly after stringify is used.
     //     for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        //    console.log(test['businesses'][i]['name']);
        //  // console.log(test['businesses'][i]);
        // }
        console.log(test['businesses'][0]['name']);
        first = test['businesses'][0]['name'];

    });
    res.render('helloworld', {
            title: 'Hello, World',
            name: first
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Try adding the call to render within the callback function after assigning the value to first.  The way it is written now, res.render is executed before first gets assigned a value, which may be why nothing displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yelp.search` is asynchronous. You have to call `res.render` inside the callback, like:

```
yelp.search({location: "tempe", term: "sandwiches", category_filter: "food"}, function(error, data) {
    var test = JSON.stringify(data); //Changes yelps response to JSON Objects with double quotes
    test = JSON.parse(test); //JSON.parse can now parse correctly after stringify is used.
 //     for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    //    console.log(test['businesses'][i]['name']);
    //  // console.log(test['businesses'][i]);
    // }
    console.log(test['businesses'][0]['name']);
    first = test['businesses'][0]['name'];

    res.render('helloworld', {
        title: 'Hello, World',
        name: first
    });
});
```

, otherwise it will be called before `yelp.search` have returned.

Answer (score 1):

It is asynchronous callback.
  When `yelp.search` exec, and callback still not exec, `name` is undefined. So your render{name: 'undefined'}.
Besides the ways of @Rodrigo Medeiros, you can also use some module to solve. e.g: `q`, `asnyc`, `bluebird` and so on.